# Is a C script compiled using "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" slower than directly compiling and running withing Windows?

Tags: c, windows, bash, gcc, cmd

I want to run a single file script written in C. I've been using the Bash On Ubuntu On Windows 10 directly from the terminal, while compiling using gcc for Linux.

I was wondering if maybe by compilying and running the script directly from Windows, for example using Windows gcc and getting a Windows executable file, would I get better performance of my script in terms of speed of execution?

The script would run faster if everything was done within Windows?

Thank you

Comment: Does your script include a shebang like `#!/bin/...`? An exe file runs faster anyway.

Comment: The problem is, is the C program portable to Windows?  If you port the program to Windows, it has the advantage of being a native program for Windows, not requiring a Linux compatibility layer or virtual machine. It could well perform faster; that's impossible to say from the information given.

Comment: What do you mean with "*Bash On Ubuntu On Windows 10*"? Is that the " Linux kernel on Windows" thing?

Comment: No It doesn't include any shebang. It is a simple data analysis script that will carry out some elaborations and simulation from a CSV file. Simulation will typically last days so ai would like to be faster."Bash On Ubuntu On Windows" is the official Windows 10 tool that allows you to have the Ubuntu shell within Windows 10.  The program should be portable to Windows. I would just like to know if using Windows will I get some speed out of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A natively-compiled program will run faster and use less memory than the script equivalent provided that:

- the language *and* source code is the same (i.e. script a C program and compile the same source code)
- the compiler is good enough (most are, unless you wrote your own compiler and are troubleshooting it)

That said, C is a great programming language, but not so easy for scripts, as it is cumbersome to run shell programs (like `grep`, `sed`, and other hugely useful commands) and pipe their output to other commands. It is possible of course (I like [`tcc`](https://bellard.org/tcc/tcc-doc.html) in that regard) but should be marginally used for anything not covered by other regular commands (and, as you're using Windows 10, PowerShell is a *huge* improvement over `cmd`, to say the least).

Now, if you want to do linux-style scripting on Windows (which is more "GNU-style" scripting), you might want to have a look at [MinGW](http://mingw.org) (Minimalist GNU for Windows). It has all the cool tools a standard Linux has (`bash`, `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, ...) which are natively compiled for Windows so you'll get mostly the same execution speed than on Linux, with the advantages of scripts over compiled programs.